# Alternative use of the word "otherwise"

Tags: sentence-construction

Otherwise, apart from its usual meaning, can also indicate **"in other respects"**   (found it in the dictionary).

When constructing a sentence using aforementioned meaning of "otherwise" are these structures acceptable and natural?

> An otherwise great movie ruined by his acting.
>
> His acting ruined an otherwise great movie.

Are there any distinct rules to follow when creating sentences in similar fashion?

Comment: It is merely an adjective there.

Comment: @Lambie: Adverb, surely? Given it's modifying an adjective...

Comment: Yes, if conditions were otherwise, is an adjective. Here, it's an adverb, right. Sorry. Going too fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's just an adverb modifying the adjective *great*. Nothing special to see here; you have used it correctly in both cases. You are saying that the movie would have been great, but *his* acting ruined it.